# How to return profiles based on how long ago they were active?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make it so that when you go to the active now page it returns all the users that were active in the past 30 minutes.
So what I've been trying to do is get the current time and then compare it to the time that the user profile was last active which will be then when they trigger a function from an onclick event which will then update a last active field in there Firestore document.

The problem is I'm not sure how to do that within the calling of the collection?
Heres where I'm getting the last active field.

```
<script>
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
export default {
    setup() {
 const {load} = getPremium();
load();
let currentDate = new Date();
let time = currentDate.getHours() * 3600 + currentDate.getMinutes() * 60 + currentDate.getSeconds();
const { documents: Premium } = getCollection(
      'Premium', 
      ['Lastactive', '>',[ time  - 1800 ] ]
    )
</script>
```

Thats what I've got so far to be honest I was getting a bit confused thinking about it so any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I am using a firestore database and here is where the composable for fetching profiles is.

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').get()

            Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
               console.log(doc.data())
               return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

I've updated time so it gets a correct number now.

Also is it possible for me to do this

```
const activenow = this.Lastactive <= (time - 1800)
```

And then take the Lastactive out of the v-for statement in the template and then go back to the template and in the <div v-if="activenow" before the v-for statement that way all the ones that aren't <= will not appear on the page??

Comment: Please provide some background as to what database you are fetching data from and what framework you are using.

Comment: I've added the page which gets the documents in the first place and i'm using firestore as the database

Comment: Why don't you use 
`const q = query(collection(db, 'collection_name'), where("Lastactive", ">", (time-1800) );
const querySnapshot= await getDocs(q);`

Comment: also check the format of `Lastactive`, maybe you are comparing two different time formats. Use the exact same format for `time` you used while creating the `lastactive` field of your document.

Comment: actually I found out it doesn't work also because when I've currentDate.getHours() + currentDate.getMinutes() + currentDate.getSeconds()  is just plusing them as it sees them I'm going to have to multiply them before hand or the numbers completely wrong.

Comment: Sorry but that one doesn't work either, Thanks though

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your last active should have date as well, not just time. Something like : `Lastactive : "22012023091550" ` where 22022023 represents the date and time is 09:15:50 . It would give you accurate results and easier to compare.

Comment: Make a method for parsing time that accepts a `new Date()` object as argument. use that method to parse both the Lastactive(parse whenever uploadating) and time variables you are using.

Comment: I get await can only be used in async function  do you mean for this const q = query(collection(db, 'collection_name'), where("Lastactive", ">", (time-1800) ); const querySnapshot= await getDocs(q); in the composable, if so it would have to be a newly created composable as that one is used for multiple pages across the website?

Comment: Wherever you use `getDocs` just make that function async. or you can use `.then` syntax as  ` getDocs(q).then(( querySnapshot)=>{
//querySnapshot contains all the docs.
});